# Variable full height layout with one variable height row and a filling area

Tags: html, css

I'm struggeling with a layout which has to support nesting and works without the use of javascript (current production solution uses js and runs into performance issues).

Unfortunately i have to support IE until IE8 so i can't use fancy stuff like a flex layout either, which would make this a trivial task.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfb7ce7f/6/) is my current attempt.

The outer 300px is just for testing purposes. The final solution has to adapt entirely onto it's parent.

By the looks of it, without flexbox/javascript this seems to be impossible, as long as the "content" row can have a variable height (otherwise it's easy to work with nesting + position + box-sizing).

I have also tried changing this:

`<td style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; ">`

including #viewportLimit to height: 100% in hopes to force them to inherit their parent height, which worked for the layout tab of firebug but had no effect on rendering.

I've run out of ideas and i hope someone can throw ideas at me.

I think the fiddle points out what i am trying to do. I want the light blue element to fill the dark blue square. That element should later on be scrollable on demand (minimal javascript required there compared to js based dimension calculation), but i can figure out that one by myself.

All i could use some help with is making it consume the full space for now.

Comment: So, what is the question? what you want to do?

Comment: @Urahara added some info for clarification.

Comment: There are no squares there.. and it's still very unclear what you are trying to make.. You know I start to think that you should reconsider your approach if it lead you to such a pickle.